# Android Keyboard Input

Tags: android

I started programming an app and on startup there is always an text input with a blinking cursor at the bottom. I have no EditText defined in the xml file and wont need any text input. 
I have no idea why it shows that part. Can anyone help me getting rid of that?

EDIT:
I added the Manifest File.

Here the current *.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="de.test.ble_benchmark.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/nodevice"
        android:id="@+id/device"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="336dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/console"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/console"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/scan"
        android:id="@+id/scan"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="134dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.tuhh.et5.tills.ble_benchmark">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        >
        <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".BlunoService"/> >

    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:

Ok, there seems to be more to it. I'm not sure, but it seems related..
I try to change the visibility of those TextViews and get a nullpointer exception. Something is messed up ...

I cant figure out. Here is the method that generates the exception:

```
public void updateUi(){

        Button scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scan);
        ProgressBar search = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
        TextView deviceName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.device);



        switch (layoutState){
            case 0:
                // close
                super.onBackPressed();
                cleanup_bluno();
                d("State 0");
                break;
            case 1:
                // Start
                d("State 1");
                search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                deviceName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                scan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            case 2:
                // Searching
                d("State 2");
                search.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                deviceName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                scan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                output.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            case 3:
                // Device Found
                d("State 3");
                search.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                deviceName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                scan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                output.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

It starts into state one and crashes when setting the Visibilities.

Comment: Have you defined any `windowSoftInputMode` state in `Menifest` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i'm a little embarrassed... Someone told me to run "invalidate Caches / Restart". Now the problem dissapeared...

Sorry for bothering and thanks for looking into it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code in your activity onCreate() method. I think the following may work

```
 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: As @jaydroider suggested I added the windowSoftInputMode to the manifest and additionally wrote the above code line into my activity. Its still the same as before. I'm not sure what it should do, but it is not about hiding the keyboard. At the bottom of the Screen there is a blinking cursor for text input. If I click it, the keyboard pops up and i can write stuff in it. When i hit "enter" it starts a new line and the written characters stay in the line above...

Comment: That means an unexpected edittext showing in your layout despite of you didn't add in this?

Comment: At least it looks like that.